# Really weird bug with a for loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, scope

So this bug seems really weird to me. I have a method with two required arguments, but when the script gets inside the first for loop, one of the two arguments seems to no longer exist.

Here's a chunk of the code:

```
public function getOptionsForParameters($params, $product){
    // here the value of $product is 105
    for($i = 0; $i<count($params); $i++){
        // but here, $product no longer exists, so in the SQL query, it is empty

        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM [table_name]
                WHERE prm_id = ".(int)$params[$i]['prm_id']."
                  AND prd_id = ".(int)$product."
                  AND opt_status = 'active'";
    } 
// ... 
}
```

I really don't understand why because there's absolutely no script between the beginning of the method and the for loop.

Also, if I print the variable after all the for loops, just before the "return" of the method, its value is 105... It seems to me that PHP somehow gives a scope to my variable, which is weird..

I've been struggling with this for too long already and I haven't found anything related to this on Google or PHP.net

Does someone has any idea why my script would do that?

BTW: My PHP version is 5.3.10

Thank you very much

Comment: Not possible with the code you posted. Please post a complete code snippet that demonstrates this behavior, preferably somewhere like http://codepad.org.

Comment: What is going on where the comments are inside the loop?  Are you wiping the variable content?  Does it not exist or is empty?  There is a difference.

Comment: Which variable is missing, the $product or $param, if it's $param, is it only something "inside" $param or the whole variable...

Comment: What does `var_dump($params)` produce if you place it *before* the loop?

Comment: @Orbling -> the comments I posted in my code snippet aren't even in my script. There is absolutely no more code than what you see here. (Except for the rest of the method, but the problem is before that)

Comment: @JonathanPellerin: If there is no more code at those locations, how do you know the value is 105 before the for loop and that it is gone before the cast?

Comment: Check the spelling, there may be a typo somewhere in your code. Add `var_dump($params)` just before the call to `getOptionsForParameters`.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't happen. Are you 100% sure it is gone? What does an isset($product) give you?

What does the following code do?

```
public function getOptionsForParameters($params, $product){
    var_dump($product);
    for($i=0; $i<4; $i++){
        var_dump(isset($product));
    }
}
```

If that still results in a set $product in the outer function and an unset $product in the inner loop, then something is very wrong in PHP itself and it is probably some bug...

On another note:

```
$i<count($params);
```

in your for-loop statement is inefficient, since it executes a count($params) *every* iteration. Better calculate it once and use that calculated value

```
$count = count($params);
$i<$count
```

Comment: isset($product) inside the for loop returns false

Comment: And what if you *just* have the for loop with the isset($product) and without any other commands (like constructing the SQL)?

Comment: and the simplified code as above in the updated answer?

Comment: I have tried it all already, before the loop, $product has a value, and right at the beginning of the loop, it doesn't even exist..

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas... It simply shouldn't happen!

Answer (score 0):

According to normal array declaration, have you tried:

```
WHERE prm_id = ".(int)$params['prm_id'][$i]."
```

as it seems to be the normal way to [declare an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532598/best-practice-how-to-structure-arrays-standards-and-naming-conventions) at least according to the question I posed about array declaration syntax?

Comment: I believe this should fix it OP. You currently have the index in the wrong location which is making things a bit flubby.

Comment: Not necessarily. It is perfectly valid for the array to be structured like this. Aside from that it is `$product` the OP complains about being "missing", not `$params`.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 It depends on the way the array is declared - though it seems that most people declare an array in the way that is described bu the code I posted. The OP *may* well have created it in the `[column][row]` manner or had a function that did so. I am just offering a suggestion.

Comment: @DaveRandom +1 from me. I am just spit-balling with this answer. It seems logical, but could well be totally useless. Intuitively it seems right, but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: The problem is with $product and not $params..

Comment: @JonathanPellerin `$product` could well be a string that is passed rather than an array. Given the names of the arrays (product and params) it seems intuitive that a product has multiple params - and is therefore being passed as a string or ID and not an array.

Comment: In fact, $product is an integer

Comment: @JonathanPellerin Thanks mate, that's a personal *bazinga* to me :)